# iOS kontakt.io beacons search

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I have two kontakt.io Beacons. I'm able to find it using the default Kontakt.io app available in the AppStore. But when I use the SDK and try to find it in my custom app, the app requests Bluetooth, which means it does something with it, but no beacons are found.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.kontakt.io/ios-sdk/quickstart/#beacons-configuration) I must only create an object of KTKBeaconManager class, assign a KTKBeaconManagerDelegate and call startFindingDevices method. After that the delegate should receive callbacks whenever devices in range changes. I extended the KTKBeaconManager with a class called BeaconManager. Here's its code (Yes I have imported everything and code compiles. I didn't put it here to save space.).

BeaconManager.h

```
@interface BeaconManager : KTKBeaconManager <KTKBluetoothManagerDelegate>
@end
```

BeaconManager.m

```
@implementation BeaconManager
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //Setting the delegate to self
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)bluetoothManager:(KTKBluetoothManager *)bluetoothManager didChangeDevices:(NSSet *)devices {
    NSLog(@"Entered didChangeDevices. Devices size: %d", devices.count);
}
@end
```

Starting the search.

```
BeaconManager *beaconManager = [BeaconManager new];
[beaconManager startFindingDevices];
[beaconManager reloadDevices]; //Tells the manager to forget all devices and start searching again.
```

This is actually a sample code from the [documentation](http://docs.kontakt.io/ios-sdk/quickstart/#beacons-configuration), but it's not working. Anybody's going through something similar and has got a clue what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your beaconManager is most probably deallocated just after it's created. You have to move it to an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not written that directly but you should know what's the scope of life for object - it should be a property if you want to have it working all the time etc.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was a beginner in Objective-C and before I worked in Java, where something like this works, so that's why I thought it might work.

Comment: Strange, in every programming language that I know local variable is deallocated when program is leaving method in which scope it exists. As far as I know the same happens in Java.

Comment: You're right, it is deallocated, the reference is destroyed, so the reference counter destroys entire object, even though there is actually some code running on that object.
Java keeps the code in an object running even though you don't have a reference on it, if the object has a reference to give a callback.